# Changed username in AD, now Windows Authentication no longer works but Forms does

Tags: iis-6, windows-authentication

We have a web based application on IIS6 that matches profiles to usernames based on what is returned via the authentication process. One of the user's usenames was changed in AD (and in the application as well to match). However, when they sign in now via Windows Authentication they are authenticated but not authorized since it seems that the old username is still coming back. When using Forms authentication the user has no problems logging in. We can not use Forms auth as a permanent solution.

Any idea if the username (samAccountName) is cached somewhere in the network, or on the local security authority on the server? Is there a way to clear this? Any other ideas as to what the issue may be?

Answer (score 0):

It's cached on the local IIS machine, but I don't remember where.

I can tell you that it's cached in a location that survives Worker Process recycles, though, so you'll either need to try IISReset (I never usually recommend that, but there you go), or reboot the box.

Comment: Thanks for that. I did recommend already to reboot the server. Unfortunately, it is a system critical server with many apps running there. So I was hoping to run some sort of command that would clear the appropriate cache.